# MySQL Foreign Key Constraint Confusion

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

Hey everyone, I have the following 'users' table in MySQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `region` tinyint(4) unsigned default NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `new_pass` varchar(5) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `role` (`role`),
  KEY `region` (`region`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`role`) REFERENCES `role` (`role`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`region`) REFERENCES `region` (`region`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have 'region' set as a foreign key to a region table - region.region'

Notice, that users.region is declared as NULL. I was under the impression that in MySQL, a foreign key contstraint is enforced ONLY if the key is set as NOT NULL.

However, when I try to insert a user with a NULL region in my PHP application, I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`reslife4/users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`region`) REFERENCES `region` (`region`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

BUT, if I were to add this user outside of my PHP application, for example in phpMyAdmin, it would allow me to.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure that your application is inserting null into the region field and not something like a zero?

To debug, I would turn off the foreign key, insert the record, and see what is there.  Is it null or did it get set to a value.

Comment: Good tip. I turned off the foreign key, and realized that my application was entering a 0 into the DB, even though in my application, if the variable is not set, then I assign NULL to it. Then I realized, the region field in the DB is an integer, so NULL will be interpreted as 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application puts a non-`NULL` value into `region`.

Enable the [**query log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and see what exactly your `PHP` tries to insert into the table.

Comment: The problem is the field in my DB is set as an int, so it will interpret NULL as 0...Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else who might run into this issue, the way to get around it is by, in your SQL query, NOT inserting the NULL value.